# send cURL Request in PHP

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I want to send a request to :
`https://api.nobitex.ir/` 
Like this : `https://api.nobitex.ir/v2/orderbook/BTCUSDT` in php or laravel. 
Can someone help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP, cURL, and HTTP POST example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-and-http-post-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below funtion to call url with php curl

```
function call_url_service_curl($service_url) {

    $curl = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'api');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 0); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); // http to https or  www to non www url available
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

and usage is

```
$result = call_url_service_curl('https://api.nobitex.ir/v2/orderbook/BTCUSDT');
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); die();
```

Answer (score -4):

Use [this website](https://reqbin.com/) it converts your curl request to any langauge